# Why am I getting column K does not exist when I am not using K as a column at all?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[The image shown above has all the records. I only want to extract fulfillment_shhipment_id||package_id where substrings are K from the inner query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ9LQ.png)I am trying to find all the records in the table where the 1st and 9th character of a string or column zone are K. The zone column has records like KXYZ_TO_KABC.

```
select * from booker.d_air_shipments_na where 
(fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id) in 
(select fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id
from booker.d_air_shipments_na 
where datediff(day, customer_order_date,ext_dea_day)<=1 
and customer_order_date>=current_Date -7
and substring(zone,1,1)=K 
and substring(zone,9,1)=K);
```

I get the correct results when I run the query as select substring(zone,1,1), substring(zone,9,1) from booker.d_air_shipments_na
and get value K in two columns.

Answer (score 3):

need single quote for K

```
select * from booker.d_air_shipments_na where 
(fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id) in 
(select fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id
from booker.d_air_shipments_na 
where datediff(day, customer_order_date,ext_dea_day)<=1 
and customer_order_date>=current_Date -7
and substring(zone,1,1)='K' 
and substring(zone,9,1)='K');
```

Comment: I get no records in the table but there are records having K in the 2 columns or substring function

Comment: @Sankalp share tables data

Comment: added an image with all the details